# Can question author accept a suggested edit that was rejected by reviewer?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I've received a suggested edit to my question which was rejected by a reviewer. Can I still accept it?

The suggested edit was correcting markup of my question. The reviewer rejected it with message "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.". Though, in my opinion, the edit was actually making the question "a little bit easier to read".

Answer (score 3):

Just make the same edit yourself. If it was so minor that it was rejected, I see no reason why it would be important to credit someone with the edit.

Comment: But then the editor will still be hit on his statistics, with one suggested edit misclassified as rejected.